# Reorganizing dataframe for time-series using reshape2 (melt and cast)

Tags: r, reshape

I'm trying to take some pieces of a dataframe and reshape them so they're fit for time-series analysis using a package like `xts` or `zoo`. For that (as far as I know), I'll need just a matrix of the time series with the values for relevant variables, set up in wide form.

It seems like `melt` and  `cast` from the `reshape2` package would be the way to do this, and I'm using the same approach found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/how-to-change-data-between-wide-and-long-formats-in-r   ...but I'm having trouble.

Let's say this is the dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15461, 15462, 15463, 15461, 
15462, 15461, 15462, 15463, 15461, 15462, 15461, 15462, 15461, 
15462, 15463), class = "Date"), Company = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fakeco", 
"Globcorp", "Renco"), class = "factor"), Region = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("amer", 
"asia", "euro"), class = "factor"), Revenue = c(141L, 467L, 168L, 
359L, 220L, 124L, 303L, 196L, 264L, 461L, 149L, 472L, 287L, 308L, 
333L)), .Names = c("Date", "Company", "Region", "Revenue"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ultimately, I want the data organized with unique date entries, with each column
a regional company, and Revenue as the values.

My first guess would be to do something like

1) Create a variable that's the combination of Company and Region so that each combination
can be one column:

```
df$coreg <- do.call(paste, c(df[c("Company", "Region")], sep= "_"))
```

2) Use `plyr` to reorganize around this new variable

```
dfply <- ddply(df, c("Date","coreg"),
    function(df) c(Revenue = sum(df[,4])))
```

3) Use the `melt` and `cast` functions from `reshape2` to reorganize the data for time-series
analysis.

```
one <- melt(dfply, id=c("Date","coreg"))

two <- dcast(one, Date ~ coreg)
```

But is there a more straightforward way of doing this? It seems like a very roundabout way
of doing a couple switches and aggregations of data and I have a feeling I'm not properly leveraging `melt` and `cast`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the format you are looking for?

```
dcast(df, Date ~ Region + Company, value.var = "Revenue")

#         Date amer_Renco asia_Fakeco asia_Globcorp euro_Fakeco euro_Globcorp euro_Renco
# 1 2012-05-01        264         287           141         149           359        124
# 2 2012-05-02        461         308           467         472           220        303
# 3 2012-05-03         NA         333           168          NA            NA        196
```

Comment: Well shoot, I had no idea it was possible to do the entire operation from one line of dcast code; this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, ignoring the warning, or use `suppressWarnings(read.zoo(df, split = 2:3))`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, split = 2:3)
```

Comment: First time I see the `split` argument in action. +1. `read.zoo` is indeed a great function!